# oVirt Snapshot Backups to Export Domain

Tags: export, backup, virtual-machine, redhat, snapshot

I'm looking for a way to perform **VM backups** for my **oVirt 3.5** environment. I came across a couple of scripts like this one: http://www.clevernetsystems.com/virtual-machines-backup-script-rhev-3/ but they shutdown each VM before the backup. It also seems like they perform a **clone** which isn't ideal.

I'd like to **avoid downtime** altogether. Does anybody know of any scripts that will perform a **snapshot** of a **live VM** and then transfer the snapshot over to the **export domain**? It would be great too if the the snapshot was deleted after the transfer as well but right now I'll take a snapshot of a live VM and the transfer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This script works nicely: https://github.com/wefixit-AT/oVirtBackup

In general, you can use the API to snapshot VM;clone snapshot to export domain; delete snapshot, and the export domain will contain a backup you can copy or use elsewhere. To restore, attache the export domain and import